# WebSphere Portal 6.0 Portlet Error Logging

Tags: logging, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

Where I can find the error logs from a portlet deployed to WebSphere Portal 6.0 (Linux)

Answer (score 3):

You will find logs in SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log

In a default Webpshere Portal 6.0 installation logs (SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log) are located under `<PortalServer>`\log\

The best way to find out the location of these file is to check in the Websphere Administration console.
In the Administration console, Under Environment > Websphere variables, look for variable SERVER`_LOG_`ROOT

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into using JCL (Jakarta Commons Logging) and Log4j instead of Portal's default logging.  But be careful, there are a couple of Logging gotchyas:

http://mycrappytechnologyblog.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/websphere-portal-log4j-hell/